# What is the point of using an "Implicitly Unwrapped Optional" as a function parameter type?

Tags: swift

I go over some code written by other developers and now and then I encounter signatures like this one:

```
func didReceiveLogMessage(_ message: String!)
```

Would it be safe to convert this parameter type to *String* instead of *String!* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically **never** declare a custom function parameter as implicit unwrapped optional. Don't.

This is a pre Swift 3 legacy syntax only for Objective-C and Core Foundation compatibility.

It's absolutely safe and even highly recommended to remove the exclamation mark. However if you really need an optional use a regular optional (`?`)

Answer (score 1):

This gives no value. It actually adds complexity as even an Inmplicitly unwrapped optional as such counts as an optional, meaning it can be nil (but will crash). a regular `String` can't be nil